# multi-class logistic regression for ordered labels

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have a set of labells:

```
      A - no lesion
      B - mild
      C - severe
```

If an instance from a class predicted as its nearest class not a big problem compare to an instance predicted as a compeletely different class.

For e.g. if A predicted as B is not a big problem compared to A predicted as C.

Are there any methods to do this? could you please suggest some readings and any public code to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need either [Ordinal Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit) (see also [here](http://statistics.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm) for R) or Cost-Sensitive Classification. 
The are a *lot* of readings and public code examples. Google including the name of your programming language